# Found duplicate execution with id default in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, execution

How to resolve issue with duplicate executions.

> 'build.pluginManagement.plugins.plugin[org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin].executions.execution.id' must be unique but found duplicate execution with id default

Here is source code:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <user>tkmadmin</user>
                    <password>ticketmaster</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 24):

Add explicit `<id>`s to your `<execution>`s:

```
<execution>
    <id>flyway-clean</id>
...
<execution>
    <id>flyway-migrate</id>
```

Reference: [Maven / POM Reference, Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins):

> - **executions**: ...
>
>   ```
>   ...
>   ```
> - **id**: Self explanatory. It specifies this execution block between all of the others. When the phase is run, it will be shown in the form: `[plugin:goal execution: id]`.